# Does the output of this system have a closed form expression?

Tags: convolution

\begin{align}
x(n)&=\left(-1\right)^n u(n)\\
h(n)&= u(n-1)+u(n-2)\\
y(n)&= x(n)*h(n)\\
y(n)&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left(-1\right)^k u(k)\left[u(n-k-1)+u(n-k-2)\right] 
\end{align}
Graphically it looks like the output is $u(n-1)$ but I can't do the math to get it into the closed form.

Edit: Ok I pretty much worked it through I'm just iffy on justifying $n \ge 1$

$u(k)$ sets the bottom limit of the summation to $0$ and $u(n-k-1)$ sets the upper limit to $n-1$. $n$ has to be at least $1$ for the summation to make sense and the partial sums = $1$.

Comment: Start by making a list of the actual values of $h[n]$ instead of gobbledygook like $u[n-1]+u[n-2]$, that is, fill in the blanks in the form below: \begin{align}h[-2] &=\\h[-1]&=\\h[0]&=\\h[1]&=\\h[2]&=\\h[3]&=\\h[4]&=\\h[5]&=\\\end{align} and then report back to us.

Comment: It's the unit step shifted right 1 unit plus the unit step shifted right 2 units. So {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 ...}. Graphically its very simple, mathematically is where I was having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You figured out the solution by yourself, so this is just about how to show it formally. First, split the sum into two sums:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^ku[k]u[n-1-k]+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^ku[k]u[n-2-k]\tag{1}$$

The unit steps give you upper and lower summation indices, but note that the resulting sums are only valid if the upper summation index is not smaller than the lower one:

$$y[n]=u[n-1]\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k+u[n-2]\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k\tag{2}$$

Now note that you can increase the upper summation index by any even number without changing the value of the sum. The second term on the right-hand side of $(2)$ can thus be rewritten as

$$u[n-2]\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k=u[n-1]\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\tag{3}$$

In $(3)$ the argument of the unit step can be changed to $n-1$ because the value of the sum equals zero for $n=1$. Using $(3)$, Eq. $(2)$ can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}y[n]&=u[n-1]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\right)\\&=u[n-1]\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k+(-1)^n\right)\\&=u[n-1]\left((1+(-1)^{n+1})+(-1)^n\right)\\&=u[n-1]\tag{4}\end{align}$$

Comment: When I simplified the summation indices I got rid of all of the unit steps all together. Would it be correct to state that the the closed form is y(n) = 1 for n >= 1?

Comment: Also, is it correct that you factored out u(n-1) and u(n-2)? Isn't the convolution sum constantly shifting them? So if k is 5 then it would be u(n-6) or u(n-7) at that iteration?

Comment: @BobShanely: Concerning your first comment, yes, it's correct to say that $y[n]=1$ for $n\ge 1$, but you also have to show that $y[n]$ is zero otherwise. (That's just the definition of $u[n-1]$). And for your other comment, you have to multiply the sums by the step functions, because both sums must be zero when the upper index is smaller than the lower index, and without the step functions this is not the case. Their indices are independent of the convolution sum, they just make the result zero if the upper summation index is smaller than the lower index.

Comment: I thought that property was inherent to the summation though. That it evaluates to 0 if the top index is lower than the bottom

Comment: @BobShanely: That's one possible definition, but it doesn't harm to make this explicit by multiplication with step functions.